# Некорректно работает функция в цикле

Tags: javascript, gsap

Вместо того чтобы анимация действовала на определенный блок,она действует на все блоки. Как это исправить?

```
<div class="grid">
<img src="http://www.tsstrade.ru/img_out/gallery_elements/archiveYeIdSI.jpg" 
     alt="" width="100" height="100" class="image" />
<div class="content" id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     Iste pariatur nesciunt quasi recusandae, voluptatem minus exercitationem, 
     consectetur, vero possimus sequi magni odio cupiditate commodi iure ut 
     accusamus neque voluptatum praesentium.</p>
</div>
```

```
  var image=document.querySelectorAll('.image');
  var content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  var wrap = document.getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0];

  var tl = new TimelineMax();
  body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  for(var i =0; i<image.length;i++){
    console.log(image[i]);
    image[i].onclick=init();
  }
  function init(){
    return function(){
     tl.add(changeBackground(),1)
    .add(changeImg(),1);
   }

  }


 function changeBackground(){
   var tl = new TimelineMax();
   tl.to(wrap,1,{
   position:'fixed',
   width:'100%',
   height:'100%',
   left:'0px',
   top:'0px',
   backgroundColor:'#fff',
   zIndex:1
  });
     return tl;
}

  function changeImg(){
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.to(content,1,{color:'red',display:'inline-block',top:'0px'},1);
    return tl;
  }
```

Comment: приведенного кода недостаточно для ответа. Что такое `TimelineMax`? `changeBackground`? `changeImg`? где описана анимация? Ну и как вариант - анимация действует на все блоки. так как в один `TimelineMax` пихаются для всех блоков

Comment: Обновил код....

Comment: на какие именно блоки? если на те который с классом content - то вы сами их все и подпихиваете

Comment: При клике на изображение (класс .image), текст с классом "content" появляется.